# asp.net mvc: how to mock Url.Content("~")?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

anybody knows how to mock `Url.Content("~")` ?

(BTW: I'm using Moq)

Comment: What is `Url`? Is it a type? A Property?

Comment: it's UrlHelper type property (get)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are referring to the `Url` property in the controllers, I presume, which is of type `UrlHelper`. The only way we have been able to mock this is to extract an `IUrlHelper` interface, and create a `UrlHelperWrapper` class that both implements it and wraps the native `UrlHelper` type. We then define a new property on our `BaseController` like so:

```
public new IUrlHelper Url
{
    get { return _urlHelper; }
    set { _urlHelper = value; }
}
```

This allows us to create mocks of `IUrlHelper` and inject them, but in the default case to use an instance of our `UrlHelperWrapper` class. Sorry it's long winded, but as you have discovered, it's a problem otherwise. It does, however, drop in without the need to change any of your `Url.Action` and similar calls in your controllers.

Here's the interface:

```
public interface IUrlHelper
{
    string Action(string actionName);
    string Action(string actionName, object routeValues);
    string Action(string actionName, string controllerName);
    string Action(string actionName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
    string Action(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues);
    string Action(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
    string Action(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, string protocol);
    string Action(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, string protocol, string hostName);
    string Content(string contentPath);
    string Encode(string url);
    string RouteUrl(object routeValues);
    string RouteUrl(string routeName);
    string RouteUrl(RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
    string RouteUrl(string routeName, object routeValues);
    string RouteUrl(string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
    string RouteUrl(string routeName, object routeValues, string protocol);
    string RouteUrl(string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, string protocol, string hostName);
}
```

I won't bother giving you the definition of `UrlHelperWrapper` - it really is just a dumb wrapper that implements this, and passes all calls through to `UrlHelper`.

Comment: actually I already did it without all this stuff, I will post my own answer

Comment: Anyone have an example of how to setup the `UrlHelperWrapper` and `BaseController` from David's answer?  I tried to implement this but could not figure out how the standard `UrlHelper` would be passed in to the BaseController's Url property.  The `UrlHelper` type is not convertable to the 'IUrlHelper'.

Answer (score 1):

```
controller.Url = Substitute.ForPartsOf<UrlHelper>();
controller.Url.Content("~").Returns("path");
```

Fell free with [ForPartsOf (Partial subs and test spies)](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/) in NUnit

Answer (score 0):

this is a method of mine that mocks the url.content (and also sets the IsAjaxRequest() to true)

```
public static void SetContextWithAjaxRequestAndUrlContent(this BaseController controller)
{
    var routes = new RouteCollection();
    RouteConfigurator.RegisterRoutesTo(routes);


    var httpContextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var respone = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();


    httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    httpContextBase.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(respone.Object);

    request.Setup(x => x.Form).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
    request.SetupGet(x => x.Headers).Returns(new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection {{"X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"}});
    request.Setup(o => o.ApplicationPath).Returns("/Account");
    request.Setup(o => o["X-Requested-With"]).Returns("XMLHttpRequest");

    respone.Setup(o => o.ApplyAppPathModifier("/Account")).Returns("/Account");

    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContextBase.Object, new RouteData(), controller);

    controller.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(controller.HttpContext, new RouteData()), routes);
}
```

Comment: That's not strictly speaking mocking the UrlHelper, so you can't set an expectation on a call to Url.Content ...

Comment: got it, I just didn't care about the expectation

Answer (score 0):

I know this content is old, but this is how I do it now:

IContentResolver.cs

```
using System.Web;

namespace Web.Controllers
{
    public interface IContentResolver
    {
        string Resolve(string imageLocation, HttpRequestBase httpRequestBase);
    }
}
```

ContentResolver.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Web.Controllers
{
    public class ContentResolver : IContentResolver
    {
        public string Resolve(string imageLocation, HttpRequestBase httpRequestBase)
        {
            return new UrlHelper(httpRequestBase.RequestContext).Content(imageLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

ContentResolverTests.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Web.Controllers;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Web.Tests.Controllers
{
    public class ContentResolverTests
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class when_resolving_the_content_images
        {
            [Test]
            public void then_should_resolve_to_proper_location()
            {
                // Arrange
                var resolver = new ContentResolver();

                // Act
                var httpContextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
                var httpRequestBase = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();

                httpContextBase.Setup(@base => @base.Request).Returns(httpRequestBase.Object);

                httpRequestBase.Setup(@base => @base.ApplicationPath).Returns("/Test");


                var requestContext = new Mock<RequestContext>();
                requestContext.SetupGet(context => context.HttpContext).Returns(httpContextBase.Object);

                httpRequestBase.SetupGet(@base => @base.RequestContext).Returns(requestContext.Object);

                var url = resolver.Resolve("~/Content/loading.gif", httpRequestBase.Object);

                // Assert
                Assert.That(url, Is.EqualTo("/Test/Content/loading.gif"));
            }
        } 
    }
}
```